# Does this code create a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

If I have a function like this:

```
function doSomething(param){
  var tempV = param;//should I even assign it to another variable?
  tempV.css('color','red');
  tempV = null;//Is this necessary?
  //Should I do param = null too?
}
```

And I run this(the code below) somewhere, possibly in another function:

```
var elementBeingPassed = $('#someElement');
doSomething(elementBeingPassed);
anotherFunctionSimilarToDoSomething(elementBeingPassed);
elementBeingPassed = null;
```

Would this create a memory leak? Are all the `x = null` statements needed?

What I want to do is to not have to query the same element all over again in all the functions, instead just query it once and pass it on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those variables are about to go out of scope anyway.

Therefore, setting them to `null` makes no difference.

Comment: Im sorry, so it does leak memory or it doesn't leak memory?

Comment: @arlon going out of scope means that there will be no more references to the variable. The [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) will remove it from memory for you, so it does *not* leak memory. You cannot free the memory manually.

Comment: @ SLaks @NanoWizard Thank you for your responses. I see I need to learn my scopes better before anything.